# Is there a way to make git log show specific amount of commits before and after a specified one?

Tags: git

My objective is to review commits that were around certain ones (candidates to be tagged as software version updates). Those ones are deep in history (hundreds of commits from now).

I wonder if I can do this with `git log`: since (as @svlasov has pointed out) "scrolling" is not the part of git and it's impossible to set the position from it, listing like 5 commits before and after the specific commit would be good enough. The closest thing I've found is to use the `--before=<date>` option like this:

- use `git show <candidate commit hash>` to see the date, like 8.12.2010;
- use `git log --oneline --before=9.12.2010` to check the commits before the candidate;
- increment the date (10.12, ...) and use the command again to check the commits after the candidate.

The main problem with this approach is that commits after the candidate could be several weeks later, so such incrementing is not particularly convenient. Any better suggestions?

Comment: Getting the nth ancestor of a commit is fairly easy, you can just use, e.g.  `revision~5` refers to the 5th generation ancestor of `revision`. You could probably combine that with `git log`'s `-n`, etc., to limit the number of commits shown from a range.

Comment: @Hasturkun using `git lo <hash>~N -n M` gives M commits *before* the (N-1)th ancestor, i.e. if the commits were done daily and the candidate is 15.06, I'll be able to see 1-10.06 while I'm looking for 10-20.06

Comment: You could set the range as `<hash>~N..<branch/tag/HEAD>`, which was what I meant (not that I've tested that), possibly also with `--reverse`

Comment: @Hasturkun well, yes, but like I wrote, the candidate commits are hundreds of commits await from HEAD, so what you suggest is still much scrolling per each commit. Although using tags reduces the amount of scrolling, I'll check if it's ok in my case

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling is outside of scope of `git log` command, since this is the job for the pager. For example using `less` you can do something like this:

```
git log | less -p <candidate commit hash>
```

Comment: [`git --no-pager log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--P).

Comment: `--no-pager` is less convenient as it has to be the first argument to `git` and it doesn't work well with shell aliases.

Comment: `cat` is not portable — not available in cmd/powershell.

Comment: According to man 1 git, `cat` or an empty string will not launch a pager, it's probably interpreted specially by git. But does it even make sense to bother disabling the pager, since the standard output is a pipe, not a terminal? AFAIU git won´t use a pager anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question taking this into account